# Elastic Search Result in List of POJO

Tags: java, elasticsearch, dsl, spring-data-elasticsearch

Currently, I am mapping the elastic search hit to a POJO  and then reiterating it to save in a list.

```
 List<Content> contentList = new ArrayList<>();
        final BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
             .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("tenantId","yes"));
        SearchHits<Content> hits = elasticsearchTemplate.search(new NativeSearchQuery(qb), Content.class,IndexCoordinates.of("preview"));
        contentList = hits.stream().map(SearchHit::getContent).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a way i can directly map the elastic result to List of Content POJO with out iterating it from Search Hit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```java
contentList = (List<Content>) SearchHitSupport.unwrapSearchHits(hits);
```